# Adding columns to header boxes using baposter?

Tags: baposter

Is there a way to add columns to the header boxes in the baposter class? I heard one can use mini pages but I’m not too sure about that. Something like a wide header box with a double column layout?

Comment: You can use the multicols environment (package multicol). Several examples files in baposter have this.

Comment: See for example https://github.com/pietvo/baposter/blob/master/figures/docs-table-example.tex